# Docker image hash by file system content only (not system metadata e.g. file created time)?

Tags: windows, docker

Is it possible to get a digest of a docker image (last layer) only by its file system content?

Nowadays when we perform docker build twice on the same Dockerfile that contains COPY commands, it won't produce the same digest, since copied files' created times inside the container's file system would differ thus produce different digests.

I would like to get the same digest when performing 2x docker build on exactly the same Dockerfile multiple times.

(using Docker on windows)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809
ADD deploy.ps1 C:\\deploy.ps1
CMD ["powershell.exe", "-File", "C:\\deploy.ps1"]
#RUN powershell -Command Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server
CMD [ "ping", "localhost", "-t" ]
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

Comment: @JohnKugelman I have build system which produces daily docker images and saves this images as .tars (named by the unique hash ID). Dockerfile (and related contents) do not change often, so we would like to reuse images as long as there are no single file system changes... That's why I am chasing some way how to identify uniqueness.

Comment: can you show the dockerfile? i suspect some udpate commands like `apt-get`

Comment: @LeiYang Added Dockerfile in the post. It's for Windows based containers, not Linux ones.

Comment: is there any file system impact after running `C:\\deploy.ps1`?

Comment: @LeiYang deploy.ps1 is literally Write-Output  this single command.